# Web server em Go aparentemente não está criando novas requisições

Tags: http, conexão, golang, webserver

Estou começando agora a desenvolver em Go, e atualmente estou estudando Go para desenvolvimento Web, então através de exemplos eu iniciei um simples servidor em Go:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "log"
  "net/http"
  "time"

  "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

var Nome string

func SetNewName(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    fmt.Println("Old Name: "+Nome)
    Nome = r.PostFormValue("nome")
    fmt.Println("New Name: "+Nome+" \n")
    w.Write([]byte("OK"))
}

//Entry point of the program
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))
    r.Handle("/", fs)

    r.HandleFunc("/teste-post", SetNewName).Methods("POST")  

    srv := &http.Server{
        Handler:      r,
        Addr:         ":8000",
        WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
        ReadTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
   }

   log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())
}
```

Na pasta *public* eu tenho um arquivo index.html simples, onde:

1) Requisita o jQuery
2) Tem um form

```
  <form id="frm-post-teste">
        <input type="text" name="nome">
        <input type="submit" id="btn-send" value="Enviar">
  </form>
```

3) E esse script:

```
$("#btn-send").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: window.location.origin+"/teste-post",
    data: $("#frm-post-teste").serialize(),
    dataType: "JSON"
  }).done(function(data){
    console.log(data)
  });

});
```

**O Problema que venho enfrentando é**: Mesmo requisições de navegadores diferentes, de aparelhos diferentes e até mesmo requisições feitas para este exemplo hospedado na DigitalOcean, todos apresentam um comportamento estranho, ao que parece a aplicação só cria uma conexão, pois a variável *Nome* tem o valor da requisição passada armazenado, isso mesmo sendo requisições diferentes realizadas por clientes diferentes.

Esse comportamento me deixou extremamente confuso, pois o código é simples e eu não sei de onde está surgindo o erro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso ocorre por conta de onde a variável está definida, quando você define:

```
var Nome string
```

Ela se torna global, acessível a tudo, portanto não apenas uma conexão.

---

Fazendo:

```
curl -X POST -d "nome=inkeliz" 127.0.0.1:8000/teste-post
```

Retorna:

```
Old Name:
New Name: inkeliz
```

Depois:

```
curl -X POST -d "nome=x" 127.0.0.1:8000/teste-post
```

Retorna:

```
Old Name: inkeliz
New Name: x
```

---

A maneira de contornar isto é definido a variável local, neste caso poderia fazer:

```
func SetNewName(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    var nome string
    //...
```

Isso irá fazer com que resulte em:

```
Old Name:
New Name: inkeliz
```

```
Old Name:
New Name: x
```

Uma outra opção seria simplesmente utilizar o `:=`, como em:

```
func SetNewName(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

    nome := r.PostFormValue("nome")

    fmt.Println("New Name: "+nome+" \n")
    w.Write([]byte("OK"))

}
```

Comment: Foi um erro conceitual, eu venho do PHP, então eu estou acostumado com uma visão diferente das coisas. No PHP a grosso modo um servidor web recebe a requisição, invoca o interpretador PHP, o interpretador então interpreta os scripts em questão(gera uma instância nova), realizada a saída aquela instância de interpretação deixa de existir. Já em Golang você dá build na aplicação, executa e essa instância de execução irá receber todas as conexões, então ao desenvolver a aplicação deve-se desenvolvê-la com essa mentalidade de instância única recebendo todas as requisições. Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 0):

É que você declarou a variável Nome em contexto global:

```
var Nome string
```

Se você quer ter contextos distintos, precisa fazer algum controle de sessão.

Parece que o Gorilla pode ajudar com isso:

https://github.com/gorilla/sessions

Comment: Se precisar passar variáveis de um método pra outro, não esquece de usar Context.